# ASP.NET MVC3 EF model Inheritance Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance

I am sure i am just missing some pretty basic here, but i can't seem to figur it out.. maybe because its been a while since i have been on the .NET platform.

Anyway, I have this database structure i the ASP.NET MVC3 framework where i have "Coruse", "Tool" and "ToolADL"(Inheritance from Tool). A "Course" can have one-or-more "Tools" where one of the "Tool"-types is "ToolADL".

Models/Course.cs:

```
public class Course {
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} er påkrævet")]
    [Display(Name = "Værktøj")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
}
```

Models/Tool.cs:

```
public abstract class Tool {
    public Tool(){
        Priority = 0;
    }
    [Key]
    public int ToolID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Models/ToolADL.cs:

```
public class ToolADL : Tool {
    [Required]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

aaand the Models/ProjectContext:

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext {
    // Course context
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    // Tools
    public DbSet<Tool> Tools { get; set; }

    // ToolADL
    public DbSet<ToolADL> ToolADLs { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i try to create the controller and connect to DbContext and the Model to it so the entity framwork can do its magic, I get the following error in the ToolADL controller Details function (and others) where time i use "find()":

ToolADLController.Details(int):

```
private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();
public ViewResult Details(int id){
    ToolADL tooladl = db.Tools.Find(id);
    return View(tooladl);
}
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project.Models.Tool'
>   to 'caREhab_community.Models.ToolADL'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Thor\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Project\Project\Project\ToolADLController.cs    29  31  Project

(I changed the name of the orginal project to "Project")

I simply cannot figur out what I am doing wrong, Is it wrong types, some really basic about Inheritance i left out or something else?

Hope some kind soul can tell me why I am an idiot and can't figure this out :)

Comment: Ok, I made some assumptions but what is the type of object that `db.Tools.Find(id)` returns in debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If object that is returned by `db.Tools.Find(id)` is of type `ToolADL` then you should do:

```
ToolADL tooladl = db.Tools.Find(id) as ToolADL;
```

After that You'll have your object or null.

If it's not of type `ToolADL` then you can't do this because:

When You have:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

You can not do something like this:

```
A a = new A();
B b = a;
```

This is in fact a basic truth about inheritance.
You might change this implicit conversion to explicit on by doing:

```
B b = (B)a;
```

Then your code would compile but You would get a runtime exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'.

To make it work You would have to specify an explicit conversion like this:

```
public class A 
{
    public static explicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

But this will give you yet another compile time error:

> 'A.explicit operator B(A)': user-defined conversions to or from a
>   derived class are not allowed

Comment: We made a change to the datastructure (due to another related error) and afterwards the error didn't occur anymore.. can't remember what we did wrong, but it was something with our knowlege being to sort on MVC3 and old on C#. But thanks so much for the answer, i didn't know some of this stuff! :)